# PyQGIS image exporter adding scale

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, export, image

In QGIS I'd like to add scale to my PyQGIS image exporter.
Similar to the `Project -> Import/Export -> Export map to image`
where you can add the scale to the image as in the picture below.

[image]

```
vLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("a_g")[0]
sExtent=vLayer.extent()
sOutputDpi= 300
sZoomScale = 2500
sQSize=QSize(10000, 10000)

settings = QgsMapSettings()
settings.setOutputSize(sQSize)
settings.setExtent(sExtent)
settings.outputDpi = sOutputDpi
settings.scale = sZoomScale

render = QgsMapRendererParallelJob(settings)

def finished():
    img = render.renderedImage()
    img.save(image_location, "png")

render.finished.connect(finished)

render.start()
```

In the output I'd like to include the scale of the map as well. At the moment the image exporter exports the image scaleless (I think) and only takes note of the `setExtent` value.

Does anyone know if it's possible to include scale in this script?

Answer (score 0):

I figured a way out to do it. The extent of the layer `vLayer.extent()`.  was bigger then the QSize of 10000px by 10000px ratio that was specified, I think that's why it scaled itself to fit in this extent.

Putting in a

`extent = iface.mapCanvas().extent()`

And further

`settings.setExtent(extent)`

Instead of the vLayer.extent() works.

Just make sure your mapCanvas is on the right scale, and then it works like a charm.